# How to change the nodata value in mosaic

Tags: raster, color, mosaic, nodata

When I add a raster to a mosaic dataset, the NoData value becomes black. How to change the NoData value back to transparent? I want to create a cache file and upload it to ArcGIS Online. If there's any way to change the NoData color in the cache file or ArcGIS Online, that would be okay too.

I tried this workaround (https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/problem-mosaic-nondata-cells-display-with-a-black-backg-000025807) but it somehow doesn't allow me to change the NoData value in step 6.